# Bounding inequalities in three dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, 3d, solid-geometry

I want to write $z^2 \ge x^2 + y^2$, $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \le  1$ and $z  \ge 0$ in the form $$a \le z \le b, \quad c(z) \le y \le d(z), \quad f(y,z) \le x \le g(y,z)$$

or

$$a \le z \le b, \quad c(z) \le x \le d(z), \quad f(x,z) \le x \le g(x,z)$$

I get $0 \le z \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-y^2} \le x \le  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-y^2}, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \le y \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, $ which is wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to answer that question as was first written.

The first form of your question implies that $z$ and $y$ have limits that are independent of each other, while the second form says the same about $z$ and $x$. But that is not the case. Here is a graph of the region.

[image]

The region is above the red cone and below the blue hemisphere. As you can see, the limits on both $x$ and $y$ do depend on the value of $z$, both in the cone part of the region and in the upper "cap" part.

Putting it another way, the limits on $x$ (or similarly on $y$) are

$$0 \le |x| \le \min(z,\sqrt{1-z^2})$$

which clearly depends on $z$.

The question would make more sense as

$$a \le z \le b, \quad c(z) \le y \le d(z), \quad f(y,z) \le x \le g(y,z)$$

or

$$a \le z \le b, \quad c(z) \le x \le d(z), \quad f(x,z) \le x \le g(x,z)$$

Using the first style, I get the answer

> $$0 \le z \le 1,$$
>   $$-\min(z,\ \sqrt{1-z^2}) \le y \le \min(z,\ \sqrt{1-z^2}),$$
>   $$-\min(\sqrt{z^2-y^2},\ \sqrt{1-z^2-y^2}) \le x \le \min(\sqrt{z^2-y^2},\ \sqrt{1-z^2-y^2})$$

How to get those: For $z$, you have $z\ge 0$, and also
$$z\le 1-x^2-y^2 \le 1$$

Once $z$ is set, for $y$ we get
$$y^2 \le z^2-x^2 \le z^2 \implies |y|\le |z|=z$$
$$y^2 \le 1-z^2-x^2 \le 1-z^2 \implies |y|\le \sqrt{1-z^2}$$
Combining those two and using $|r|\le s \implies -s\le r\le s$ gives the limits on $y$.

Once $z$ and $y$ are set, for $x$ we get
$$x^2 \le z^2-y^2 \implies |x|\le \sqrt{z^2-y^2}$$
$$x^2 \le 1-z^2-y^2 \implies |x|\le \sqrt{1-z^2-y^2}$$
Combining those two gives the limits on $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it make sense now? I want to write $z^2 \ge x^2 + y^2$, $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \le  1, z  \ge 0$ in the form $a \le z \le b$, $f(y, z) \le x \le g(y, z)$, and $c \le y \le d$. Or $a \le z \le b$, $f(x, z) \le y \le g(x, z), c \le x \le d$

Comment: Or should the form be $a \le z \le b$, $f(y, z) \le x \le g(y, z)$, and $h(x, z) \le y \le k(x, z)$? Basically I want to bound the inequalities in terms of $x, y, z$.

Comment: @user129566: No. If the absolute limits $a,b$ are placed on $z$ then the limits on $y$ or $x$ must depend on the value of $z$, but you have them as the absolute limits $c,d$. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I was after! Do you mind adding a bit about how to find the final inequalities algebraically, if isn't a bother? I know how to get the first ($0 \le z \le 1$) but not the other two.